# How do you bit-shift in RISC-V?

Tags: memory-management, numeral-representations

In the following video on computer organization:

https://youtu.be/DoR505t8-7I?t=114

the instructor displays the following:

[image]

and says that the hex string `0xFFFFFF00` is equivalent to -256.  After doing a calculation to see this represented in two's complement, this makes sense to me.  For my question below it'll help to represent this bitwise as

```
1111|...|1111|0000|0000
```

Also, these instructions are in RISC-V so they are stored in the little-endian system, so in memory this is actually stored as

```
0000|0000|1111|...|1111
```

The second line calls for a left logical shift of `0xFFFFFF00` and I can't quite understand how it's supposed to turn into `0xFFFFF800`.  If we shift in the little-endian bit picture, you would get

```
0000|0001|1111|...|1110
```

and this is so far from the given value that I'm sure this is not how it's supposed to be done.  But also if we bit shift in the picture before writing it in little-endian, we would get

```
1111|...|1111|1110|0000|0000
```

and this is `0xFFFFFE00` not `0xFFFFF800`.  Am I making a mistake here, is the prof making a mistake, or does the endian system somehow also flip the bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just now realizing that I neglected to notice the 3 in the second line of code, indicating that the bits are shifted three times.  I guess in RISC-V we shift in some way so that you can think about the usual representation rather than little-endian, and therefore the bit shift looks like this

```
1111|...|1000|0000|0000|
```

and indeed that is `0xFFFFF800`.

Answer (score 0):

When you shift, you don’t shift memory, you shift values. The result of shifting 0xffffff00 left by one bit position is the same whether the processor is bigendian or littleendian.

Shifting to the left by k bits multiplies by 2^k, shifting to the right divides by 2^k (roughly. Signed integers can be interesting).